# Background callbacks Dash

Tags: python, background, plotly-dash

I have a problem with the using of background callbacks.
the project is to read data from and store it into SQLite that is the background callback
the second callback it to read from db and plot it in real time.
I am trying the background because of the use of dcc.Interval will not allow the user to do anything but to wait for the plot to finish to keep the interval timing accuracy.
The call count of the callback stays by 0 !
has anyone any idea to help ?
Thank you

My code:

```
celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker="redis://localhost:6379/0", backend="redis://localhost:6379/1")
background_callback_manager = CeleryManager(celery_app)


@dash.callback(Output(component_id='background_store', component_property='data'),
              Input(component_id='background_interval', component_property='n_intervals'), 
            
              Input(component_id='switch', component_property='on'), 
              Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value'), 
              
              
              background=True,
              manager=background_callback_manager,
              )
            
              
def background_acquisition(n , on, dropdown, ):
    ADC_Value = ADC.ADS1256_GetAll()

    data = [] #array for figure then append data for each dropdown value 
    
    
    
    if on == False: #switch on/off 
        no_update
        return no_update
    else:
        
        
        conn = sqlite3.connect(messen)
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO time (unix, time) VALUES ( ?, ?)", (unix_time ,  time_stamp)) #insert globale time value in time table-> x axe.   (unix timestamp to test the accuracy)
        conn.commit()
        
        .... #
            
        
        
        
        
        #update x2 and gloabe waiting time for interval  and  subtract process time from waiting time to keep waiting time 1 sec    
        
        
#callback graphing 
        
@app.callback(Output(component_id='live-graph', component_property='figure'), 
              Input(component_id='update_Graph', component_property='n_intervals'), 
              Input(component_id='switch', component_property='on'), 
              Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value'), 
              )
            
              
def updating_graph(n , on, dropdown):
    #the graphing funtion thats working
```

[image]

Comment: Have you managed to get this working without the dcc.interval? With a button or some other trigger?